# ruby error of "block in initialize: uninitialized constant" but running well with irb

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script as following:

```
class HashSet < Hash
  def initialize
    super { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new }
  end
end

data = {}
data["hash"] ||= HashSet.new
data["hash"]["colors"].add "blue"
puts data
```

An error is raised when run this script:

```
$ ruby demo.rb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from demo.rb:9:in `<main>'
    1: from demo.rb:9:in `[]'
demo.rb:3:in `block in initialize': uninitialized constant HashSet::Set (NameError)
```

But when I run it with **irb**, it runs well:

```
$ irb -r ./demo.rb 
{"hash"=>{"colors"=>#<Set: {"blue"}>}}
```

What makes the difference and how can I fix the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the top of your script:

```
require "set"
```

## Explanation:

`Set` is not part of the ruby *core* library. Rather, [it is part of the ruby *standard* library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).

In order to use `Set`, you must - somewhere - `require` the library explicitly.

As it happens, `irb` actually already requires `set` as part of its initialisation process:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Set
=> Set

$ ruby -e 'Set'
Traceback (most recent call last):
-e:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Set (NameError)
```

Comment: I'm new to ruby and a little surprised that `Set` is not a builtin or part of the core library. And I have better understanding of the error message now, thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, the slightly confusing error message: `uninitialized constant HashSet::Set` is because you are referencing the `Set` class from **inside the `HashSet` class**. Now, whilst there's absolutely nothing *wrong* with doing that, ruby will first try to look for a `HashSet::Set` class and *then* try looking for a top-level `Set` class. And since it found neither, it picks `HashSet::Set` as the class name in the error message.

Comment: To prevent ruby from even looking for the non-existent `HashSet::Set`, and also prevent this confusing error message, you can explicitly tell ruby to only look for `Set` as a top-level class: Use `::Set.new` instead of `Set.new`.